# how to present the prediction together with original data using RandomForestRegressor?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-mining, prediction

I am trying to predict a label from data in a DataFrame, with RandomForestRegressor.

For that I first remove useless columns, so that the regressor does not try to use them, especially row's ID, then use a get_dummy() function to change string values into indicators, and then split the data into training and test samples.

```
# columns selection (let say there was also a column 'ID' so we drop this one)
features = features[['L', 'A', 'B']] 

# string to indicators
features = pd.get_dummies(features) 

# Saving labels
labels = np.array(features['L']) 

# Remove the labels from the features
features = features.drop('L', axis = 1) 

# Convert to numpy array
features = np.array(features)

# Divide into training and testing samples
train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 42)

# Instantiate model and fit
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 100, random_state = 42, max_depth = 8)
rf.fit(train_features, train_labels)

# predict
predictions = rf.predict(test_features)
```

So at this stage I have a sample data looking like

```
A   B_b1 B_b2
1   0    1
2   1    0
```

And predictions looking like
L
100
200

How can I, after getting the prediction, put it next to the original data, given the link with ID is lost? I expect something like:

```
ID   A   B    L
11   1   b2   100
12   2   b1   200
```

I can think of complex ways (mainly because of the conversion from pd.dataframe to np.array), but what would be the most straight forward and readable (not most efficient) way? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`predictions` and `test_features` should have the same length, so you can just lump them together in a Dataframe:

```
results = pd.DataFrame(test_features, columns=["A", "B"])
results["L"] = predictions
```

However, I would also say that you don't need to go through the step of converting `features` to a np.array, since `train_test_split` and `rf.fit` will both accept pandas.DataFrame as inputs.

Comment: Thank you Toby, actually there is still the part with dummies transforming the strings into indicator columns.. but great piece of advice, to skip the conversion to numpy array. It is indeed simpler!